# Mysql query SELECT DISTINCT month/year

Tags: php, mysql

I am struggling to figure the correct mysql query for this one...

I have a table named 'blog' with blog entries in it. Each entry has a datetime column (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS) named 'created.' I'd like to list on my page's sidebar all the distinct month-years in which an entry was written so the user can easy find older entries from the blog archive.

I have a user-defined function that my BlogEntry class uses to query the database. Based on the query, it returns an array of records. For example...

```
$entries = BlogEntry::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY created DESC");
```

What query can I use to return only the distinct month-years where an entry was written?

I've tried a few things (with no luck) such as:

```
$months = BlogEntry::find_by_sql("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(created) FROM blog");
```

Any ideas or suggestions on how to return the distinct months and years would be much appreciated!

UPDATE:
Perhaps my issue is in how to display the returned records. I've been trying the following...

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($months as $month): ?>
<li><?php echo $month->created; ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I know this doesn't look right. How could I formate it to list Month-YYYY ?

Comment: See the update of my answer : now the format of the output in the query should be what you desire ...

Answer (score 8):

`$months = BlogEntry::find_by_sql("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m-%Y') AS created_month FROM blog GROUP BY created_month");`

Should do the trick aswell?

[DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Comment: The query does work, however my issue is in how I am displaying the records. If you could, please see my update... any suggestions?

Comment: Fixed. You can change this here: `DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m-%Y')`

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for also I know the length of the dates will not change for a long time :) but wouldn't this be more clean? `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created, '%m-%Y') as createdshort FROM posts GROUP BY createdshort`

Comment: You're correct. This post is old as dust, and could use an update.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this .

```
select distinct(DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m-%Y')) from table_name 
where  order by DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y') asc,DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%m') asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL use like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(update_date,'%b %Y')) as archive_dt FROM tbl_articles
```